# Offline google map for ios application

Tags: objective-c, google-maps, ipad, ios9, offline-caching

I want to use google offline maps from my ios native application which requires downloading the files from their server.How do I implement it?

Comment: Have you explored the Google maps SDK for iOS?

Comment: Yes.But not found a relevant option.